# how to implement retry button for an axios api call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have an api call that checks if a celphone is valid and whenever it fails due to http 50x error I would like to be able to hit the "retry" button and it will call the api that failed without calling the function authenticateTel().
This is what I have so far.

I have tried looking into axios-retry but the implementation is very different to what I am trying to do like I don't need timeout since it would be the user that will try to retry the api.

index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click.prevent="authenticateTel()">validate</button>
    <button v-if="errors">retry</button>
  </div>
</template>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      tel: "12345678910"
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async authenticateTel() {
      this.formReady = false
      let res = await this.$UserApi.authenticateTel({
        tel: this.tel
      })
    },
  }
}
```

UserApi.js

```
import qs from "qs"
export default axios => ({
  authenticateTel(params) {
    let config = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "/authenticateTel",
      data: qs.stringify(params)
    }
    return axios(config)
      .then(response => response.data.data)
      .catch(err => {
        throw err
      })
  },
})
```